# Heroku buildpack ssh config and CI pipelines

Tags: git, github, heroku, ssh, pip

I'd like to have my python app depend on a private github repo (say ORG/REPO).  I've added the line `git+ssh://git@github.com/ORG/REPO.git` to my requirements.txt and followed the steps in https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/heroku/heroku-buildpack-ssh-key.  I've also tried adding the same BUILDPACK_SSH_KEY config var to the pipeline-level 'Test run config vars'.

BUILDPACK_SSH_KEY is a github deploy key

However, when I run tests in CI I'm getting an error:

```
Host key verification failed.
         fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
       
         Please make sure you have the correct access rights
         and the repository exists.
         error: subprocess-exited-with-error

git clone --filter=blob:none --quiet 'ssh://****@github.com/ORG/REPO.git' /tmp/pip-req-build-v9dtvjom did not run successfully.
         │ exit code: 128
         ╰─> See above for output.
```

Do these features (buildpack ssh config and pipelines) work together?

Comment: `Host key verification failed` means that you haven't called up GitHub before, and the fingerprint they're sending doesn't match the (nonexistent) fingerprint that you have; *or* that you *have* called up GitHub before, and the fingerprint they're sending now doesn't match the fingerprint you have. Either way your deployment machine's ssh doesn't trust the machine that is claiming to be GitHub. Figure out why not, and fix that.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out - for ci the buildpacks are defined in app.json, not via the buildpacks:set command

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> ssh://****@github.com/ORG/REPO.git
> ```

I hope the `****` is actually '`git`', as in `ssh://git@github.com/ORG/REPO.git`.

Because if it is anything else..., an SSH query to GitHub will *not* work, no matter the SSH key used is.
So make sure to use '`git`' as a user for the SSH URL.

Comment: Yes, it is 'git'

Comment: @alex OK, that must be the CICD which obfuscates the user in any SSH URL for some (security?) reason.